# What is the difference between するはずだった andしたはずだった

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, tense

I have confusion with the past tense of verb combined with the past tense of はず したはずだった

From what I understand:

1. するはず - Supposed to do verb at some point in the future (don't know
   outcome yet)
2. したはず - Verb is supposed to happen at some point in the past (don't
   know whether the verb happened)
3. するはずだった - Verb was supposed to happen (but it didn't) - am I
   speaking in the present?
4. したはずだった - Verb was supposed to happen in the past? (but it didn't)

For example, what are the differences between 3 and 4 in this sentence?

> 1. 彼女は一時までに電話**するはずだ** - She is supposed to call by 1 o'clock
> 2. 彼女は一時までに電話**したはずだ** - I suppose she called by 1 o'clock
> 3. 彼女は一時までに電話**するはずだった** - She was supposed to call by 1 o'clock
> 4. 彼女は一時までに電話**したはずだった** - She was supposed to have called by 1 o'clock?

And in this sentence:

> あれ、携帯電話がない！うちを出るとき、カバンに（**X**）けど、カバンに入れ忘れたかもしれないね。?

Which is correct (X) and why?

1. 入れるはずだった
2. 入れたはずだ
3. 入れたはずだった

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence 3 means "She was supposed to call by 1 o'clock, but she didn't.

The sentence 4 means "She was supposed to have called by 1 o'clock, but we don't know she actually called by 1 o'clock. She may misunderstand it".

As for your second question, カバンに入れたはずだけど is best.

Comment: I still don't understand completely. What is the difference between 彼女は一時までに電話したはずだ  and 彼女は一時までに電話したはずだった then? I understand はずだ means the speaker does not know whether she called at 1 o'clock, but wouldn't that be the same meaning as はずだった？And also, would カバンに入れたはずだった be correct? in the sentence above? Can you please explain further? Thanks!

Comment: したはずだ is "I am supposed to have done it", it is a view from the present. したはずだった is " I was supposed to have done it", It is a view from the past. I think カバンに入れたはずだけど is better because it is a view from the present.